# Visual Studio WinAPI как поменять значок exe файла?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

изначально в новом проекте есть своя иконка, я хотел бы поменять на свою
На картинке стандартные иконки, как заменить на свои?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поменяйте иконки в ресурсах и пересоберите.

Comment: спасибо, сегодня попробовал работает